Setting similar yaxis between 2 graphs for a ggplot code with an interaction
My problems is that I have two interaction plots, one for psychological and one for somatic complaints. I want to portray them next to each other using the code cowplot. I would like to have similar yaxis (e.g., 1.75-2.75). But when setting the yaxis similar, the interaction disappear.
The code looks like this with no specification of the y-axis since it will mess up the graph):
# Plot for psychological complaints 
plot_psychological <- ggplot(final_overall, aes(x = surveyyear, y = psycho, color = FAS_cat, group = FAS_cat)) +   
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", span = .8, se = FALSE) +   
  labs(x = "Survey Year", y = "Psychological Complaints", title = "Survey Year vs Psychological Complaints per FAS category") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Below Average" = "blue", "Average" = "green", "Above Average" = "red"), name = "Family SES categories") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2002, 2022, by = 4), limits = c(2002, 2022)) +
  theme_minimal() +   
  labs(color = "Family SES categories")
# Plot for somatic complaints 
plot_somatic <- ggplot(final_overall, aes(x = surveyyear, y = somatic, color = FAS_cat, group = FAS_cat)) +   
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", span = .8, se = FALSE) +   
  labs(x = "Survey Year", y = "Somatic Complaints", title = "Survey Year vs Somatic Complaints per FAS category") +   
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Below Average" = "blue", "Average" = "green", "Above Average" = "red"), name = "Family SES categories") +   
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2002, 2022, by = 4), limits = c(2002, 2022)) +
  theme_minimal() +   
  labs(color = "Family SES categories")

# Combine the plots with different y-axes 
library(cowplot)
# Combine plots with shared y-axis limits 
combined_plot <- plot_grid(plot_psychological, plot_somatic, nrow = 1, align = "v")
# Print the combined plot 
print(combined_plot)

I tried the following by adding these lines in the ggplot codes:

scale_y_continuous(limits = c(1.75, 2.75)) --> failed
coord_cartesian(ylim = c(1.75, 2.75)) --> failed
ylim(1.75, 2.75) --> failed

With failing I mean that I have now only one line in the plot, instead of three (based on the variable 'FAS_cat').

Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the code you ran and the output of dput(final_overall). Or, if it is too big with the output of dput(head(final_overall, 20)).

@RuiBarradas here you have 10 cases: structure(list(psycho = structure(c(1.75, 2.5, 3.25, 2, 2.5,  1.5, 2.25, 1.75, 1, 4.25), format.stata = "%9.0g"), somatic = structure(c(1.5,  2, 2.75, 1.25, 2.5, 1, 1.25, 1, 1, 1.75), format.stata = "%9.0g"),      surveyyear = structure(c(2022, 2022, 2010, 2002, 2014, 2022,      2018, 2018, 2014, 2014), format.stata = "%9.0g"),      FAS_cat = structure(c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2), format.stata = "%13.0g", class = c("haven_labelled",      "vctrs_vctr", "double"))), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame"))
